# Change micro plug to speaker plug

Tags: sound

I'm planning a little trip in bus with one of my friend, I'd like to bring my netbook so we can watch movie during it. But I have only one plug for headphone and I don't want to buy a jack multiplier.

What I'd like to do is mirror the speaker plug to the microphone plug, is this possible in ubuntu ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

This is very much depending on your hardware, but most probably for notebooks/netbooks: **no**.

However, it *is* common to be able to share the physical input jack for both line-in and microphone input modes. Both modes are related to *input*, usually. On some desktops I've seen the ability to change the output configuration mode from stereo to 6-channel output to configure the three jacks as output.

To see the options for your sound card I know of the following two options:

- Install [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol] and see what your port options are at the *Input Devices* tab:

  [image]
- Use the `alsamixer` from the terminal and select the *Mic Jack Mode*:

  [image]

Again, this is very much hardware dependent and based on the information in your question there's no way to tell your hardware has this capability or the one you ask for. Just try to see what your options are.